# Gtk Button inner-border

Tags: gtk, widget, pygtk

I add a button to HBox, with expand equal to False, but I want the button to have more spacing between its label and border. I assume it is "inner-border" property, but it is read-only. How can I set it to e.g. 4px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gtk.Label is a subclass of gtk.Misc which has the method set_padding. If you get the label out of the gtk.Button then you can just call set_padding on it.

You could do something like:

```
label = gtk.Label("Hello World")
button = gtk.Button()

/* Add 10 pixels border around the label */
label.set_padding(10, 10)

/* Add the label to the button */
button.add(label)

/* Show the label as the button will assume it is already shown */
label.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! :)
py code, if anyone needs it: some_btn.get_children()[0].set_padding(10,10)

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong answer:**

What you're looking for is called **"padding"**. When you add your button to the container, for example by calling [gtk.Box.pack_start](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkbox.html#method-gtkbox--pack-start), just set the `padding` parameter to a positive integer.

**Update:**

Seems I misread the question. In that case, my guess is that you're supposed to use [gtk_widget_modify_style](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-modify-style), as `inner-border` is a style property. You'll first get the style modifier you need by calling [gtk_widget_get_modifier_style](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-modifier-style). You'll then be able to modify the style only for that button using the [ressource styles matching rules](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-Resource-Files.html#gtk-Resource-Files.description).

Comment: The question is on INNER border of button, not padding.

Comment: I've fixed my answer (you'll need to adapt from C to Python however) , please reconsider it...

Answer (score 0):

you can use "inner-border" style property of gtk button.

here, small code snippets

```
In gtkrc file:

  style "button_style"
  {
   GtkButton::inner-border = {10,10,10,10}
  }
  class "GtkButton" style "button_style"

In .py file:

  gtk.rc_parse(rc_file_path + rc_file)
```

**[Edit]**

In gtkrc file:

```
  style "button_style"
  {
   GtkButton::inner-border = {10,10,10,10}
  }
  widget "*.StyleButton" style "button_style" # apply style for specific name of widget


In .py file:

  gtk.rc_parse(rc_file_path + rc_file)

  #set name of button
  self.style_button.set_name('StyleButton')
```

hope, it would be helpful.

Comment: this would change all of the buttons, I only need to change this one button.

Answer (score -1):

I sometimes just add spaces in the label !

```
gtk.Button("  Label  ")
```

to get some spacing.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: heh, it works, but it isn't really a "legit" way. Isn't there a proper way to achieve this?